# Books for ordinary differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

In every book of the ordinary differential equations that i have it is given existence and uniqueness theory of ordinary differential equations locally i.e. existence of solution in some neighbourhood of the given point. I am searching results and theorems regarding globally existence of solutions of ordinary differential equations. Please suggest some books for self study that has such materials. Thanks.

Comment: Teschl discusses global existence and uniqueness of solutions in his Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems book I think. The book should be available online on the author's webpage if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @MisterRiemann In which chapter of the book?

Comment: @MisterRiemann at page no $50$ i think it is given some related results

Comment: Check out Corollary 2.6 in chapter 2.3 (page 41).

Comment: @MisterRiemann  Theorem $2.17$ says existence of solution on whole real line...

Comment: @MisterRiemann yes ...thanks... Please if possible suggest  more books...

Comment: http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~elias/2008-JMAA-global.pdf, http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/research/papers/TRENCH_RP_47.PDF